# It is ok to delete using GET if im using Spring MVC with Spring security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

It is ok to delete using GET if im using Spring MVC with Spring security? I can secure /entity/delete/{id} path to a group of users.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "is it ok"? It will work, yes. It would be clearer to use the actual DELETE  verb. You can use Spring's [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) to achieve this, while securing the URL with Spring Security using something like this:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/entity/**" method="DELETE" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```